# Referencing Print page numbers from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a CSS @page property to display page numbers at the bottom of my print pages.
I'm doing this in order to make sure a table is not spanning over two pages.

How can I pull the number from the print page into Javascript so I can reference the page I'm on? Is this possible.

**Note: I tried all the non-breaking-table CSS properties none of them work correctly for webkit browsers, I need a better solution.**

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```